# Java 2D game menu

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I'm making a swing Java board game, but aside from a JTextPane for the Chat, everything have been done using java 2D.

So, I would like to know the best way to implement a "Start Game" menu with some options like (Join Game, Create Game, Options, Quit).

- Should I draw the options using java 2D or create a class menuOption extending something like a JLabel?
- And Should I create a JPanel for each menu level, if so, what is the best way to change from one JPanel to another?

I could simple use a MenuBar but it doesn't look so nice.

Thanks

Comment: This should be retagged from "2d" to "java-2d".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sice it's an opinion what you want, i'll just give you mine, but in the end it all depends on you criteria.

I like more the canvas, since it's all drawing and i like the way the menu is made up, so i think java 2D, it's i nice way to do it

I don't like the JPanel nor the MenuBar, since both of them look very ...simple, they are too common, and what i want in my geames, it's a little of originality, that's way i like to draw it all.

Comment: Yea, I like to draw everything too, but handle the mouse clicks becomes a problem to me, by now I'm checking if the mouse click coordinates are inside of the options bounds to know which one I clicked, but I believe that's not the right approach.

Comment: You can always override methods, you know, i think that shapes can handle mouse events, i barely remember java right now, it's been a while since the last time i use it

Answer (score 1):

Best way to change [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) is using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).